# get the power number from scientific notated number of a pandas Dataframe string

Tags: python, pandas, precision

By reading a tab-delimited file with pandas I get a dataframe with strings that *could* be converted to a number using `to_numeric()`, BUT most of the numbers are so small that even `float64` precision is insuffcient (e.g. `1,234e-4500`)

Setting them to `0` is not an option (calculating, plotting & differentiate). Therefore mantissa and exponent should find their way to the dataframe separately.

How can I most easily transform the string and keep both values together as numbers?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think that you actually want the data to be normalized, which would be more helpful

Comment: good point about normalizing.  in general, more info here is needed in terms of what exactly you're trying to do since numpy & pandas won't be able to work in the standard ways (although they could if you normalize into 64bit floats)

Answer (score 2):

If it's convenient enough to store both values in the DataFrame as a tuple, you can do it using a converter function of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # list of columns to be converted
converters = {
    key: lambda x:
        (
            float(x.lower().split("e")[0].replace(",", ".")),
            int(x.lower().split("e")[1])
        ) for key in columns
}
df = pd.read_csv(
    "test.csv",   # your source file
    sep="\s+",    # tabs and whitespace as separator
    converters=converters,
)
```

Having the sourcefile `test.csv` with this

```
a    b    c
1,234e-4500 2,34e-3432  9,12e-123122
```

yields as a result

```
print df
print df['a'].dtype

            a              b                c
0  (1.234, -4500)  (2.34, -3432)  (9.12, -123122)
object
```

**Sidenote**: As pointed out by vladimir, a normalization of the data *should* be a preferred approach if the problem allows for that solution.

Comment: Thanks yes this helps - it's weird but actually seems to be the best solution

Comment: Depends on what you want to do next, as vladimir and JohnE pointed out.